# How do I change a DevExpress project's theme after creation?

Tags: c#, .net, css, devexpress

I've created a DevExpress Web project (.NET) and picked a theme in the wizard. I'm now having some sizing issues with the theme and can't figure out how to change the theme without creating a new project and going through the wizard again, and then copying my code to the new project.

I'm assuming there's a setting somewhere that I'm missing. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: [Project Wizard](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11614/Choose%20Theme) documentation

The Choose Theme tab allows you to specify a theme to be applied to your site. You can use [Available Themes](http://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/CustomDocument6655.aspx) or add a custom theme from a dll file.

The selected theme specifies the theme settings of the devExpress configuration section.

*aspx*

```
<devExpress>
     <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="Aqua" />
     ...
</devExpress>
```

Source: [Web Application Template](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11827)

- The template registers the devExpress Element and adds it with the default settings to the Web.config file.

*aspx*

```
<configSections>
     <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
          <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v12.1, Version=12.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
          <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v12.1, Version=12.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
          <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v12.1, Version=12.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
          <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v12.1, Version=12.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
     </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
...
<devExpress>
     <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="DevEx" />
     <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="true" />
     <settings rightToLeft="false" />
     <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl="" />
</devExpress>
```

- The template specifies Web.config options that you set in the Wizard.

Go through these documentation links and try to modify these settings as you require.

Comment: I knew I missed something simple. Thanks!